# Magento 2 Import Error

Tags: magento2, import

Upon importing our product database I encounter the following error when pressing "Check Data"

> General system exception happened

My image file directory is point to: **pub/media/import/images**

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: the normal case it give you more details (click link show more). if not go to var System.log or Exception.log for getting more details

Comment: I've cleared my logs, re-uploaded the CSV but the error doesn't write any data to the system.log and exception.log does not exist in that directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this and after doing random 1 line imports, I found it was some characters in the descriptions. I had to open the csv in Notepad++ and go Encoding> Convert to UTF-8-BOM then save it as a copy. Went straight on then.

Comment: This is not working for me. I have done whatever have you mention in your answer. I am using version 2.0.2

Comment: You can check it out here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108407/magento-2-unable-to-import

Answer (score 6):

Found the problem.

do not use `”` in the description...make sure you use `"`

Answer (score 1):

Okay so, as user3572565 pointed out, this seems to be an issue related to encoding. If the encoding has not fixed your issue try importing using dataflow as that bypasses certain checks.

Answer (score 1):

Any non standard chars cause it to fail. quotes, questionmarks, tidles, number representations like 1 quarter, ie 1/4 but subscript version,  degrees symbols,

my advice is to convert your descriptions to html coded, so these special chars are read, correctly. if that fails remove all nonstandard alpha numerics from your descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

descriptions have to start with a html paragraph and end with a html paragraph break use excel to add the html code to the beginning and end of your description lines , example in column a4 type...

=CONCATENATE(a1,a2,a3)

in column a1 put a html paragraph break* and html paragraph closer* in column a3

*this comment box is html driven so i can't give example of a paragraph break

put your description data into a2

double click the result in a4 in bottom left corner of the a4 column to copy the command to the entirety of rows you have in your spreadsheet.

then copy the colum and paste into a5 and click the paster function that appears at the bottom of the paste and select values. then you can copy this back into your csv file , descriptions.

or use emagicone magento storemanager, is the only other solution ive used to get it working correctly, if you install that choose not to use there plugin and use direct database connection and it will allow more then 3000 entries.

please note that the above software is a trial, and I do not work for them in anyway. it just a suggestion to make importing easier.