# Magento 2 : Unable to import

Tags: magento2, import, importexport

I am working on product import section and i am facing following issue during import csv.

> General system exception happened 
>   Additional data: URL key for specified store already exists.

**Scenario to occur this issue:**

I have imported product csv before some day in `fresh installation` of magento 2, its working fine. But after delete some product and then import same product csv. Above issue has been raised.

[image]

Note : i have checked into magento 2.0.0 to 2.0.2

**CSV FILE** : http://we.tl/8nxdFSDp8R

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There where few bugs in `import` and `export` functionalities in magento 2.

Upgrade your system to 2.0.2 and see if this error occurs.

Select `Import Behavior` as `Add/Update` your CSV is perfect and is working fine.

Find the image below:[image]

File is successfully imported.

Catalog Imported:

[image]

Comment: Export your current catalog and map that CSV with the CSV you are trying to import and check if they are similar or not.

Comment: i have checked too

Comment: @zedBlackbeard : Can you share sample that CSV here? Also tell me know which `Import Behavior` you are following?

Comment: Csv file link @DEEPJOSHI : http://we.tl/8nxdFSDp8R

Comment: Which `Import Behavior`you are using?

Comment: Import behavior is  `add/update`

Comment: can you delete all the imported products again and import again.

Comment: Yes it is working with the expected behavior.

Comment: Refer for brief info:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1225

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2013

Comment: have you delete all the prdoucts and import again ?

Comment: can you show me the imported products ?

Comment: Find the screenshot i updated

Comment: Have to done with re-import  after deletion of all products. I think first time easily imported .

Comment: Yes i have imported it thrice.

Comment: This is not working for me, i don't know why. Thank you :(

Comment: Try with `Import Behavior` as `Replace`.

Comment: already tried `replace` behaviour

Comment: Yes that works. If you delete all the products from the backend and do an import it works.