# "General system exception happened" Error when doing the import process

Tags: magento2, import, importexport, exception

I have had problems when importing, I get that error, I attach the file I used at the time of import
Does anyone know how to solve the problem?
My version of magento is 2.1.6
[image: Error]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fe9nv4EvZ2sgYYCMYWA5QtcwRfFiX61t/view?usp=sharing
This is the link where the file is

Comment: Refer this links you can help for same.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6924
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98075/magento-2-import-error

Answer (score 0):

We can able to overcome the issue by creating a new source (Stores -> Inventory -> Sources) with code 'default'.

While debugging, It tries to insert the data into inventory_source_item table with source_code = 'default'. And since that source_code is a foreign key to the inventory_source table, it showed the error. When creating the source with code 'default', it then fixed the issue.